# Class Not Exist when loading entity Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I create a bundle and Entity inside the bundle. But when i try to get the entity or repository in controller using the entity manager it give an error that class not exist.

I try to debug using **php app/console doctrine:mapping:info**

it prompts every thing is correct. Output

```
Found 4 mapped entities:
[OK]   Bitcoin\MyBundle\Entity\ProductCategory
[OK]   Bitcoin\MyBundle\Entity\AdminUser
[OK]   Bitcoin\MyBundle\Entity\Product
[OK]   Bitcoin\MyBundle\Entity\User
```

My Controller code is as follows

```
<?php

namespace Bitcoin\MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Bitcoin\AdminBundle\Form\Login;
use Bitcoin\AdminBundle\Form\LoginValidate;

class LoginController extends Controller {

    public function loginAction(Request $request) {
        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('User');
        echo '<pre>';
        prin_r(get_class_methods(get_class($user))); 
        die;


    $pageData = array(
        'name' => 'Login',
    );
    return $this->render('BitcoinAdminBundle:Login:login.html.twig', $pageData);
}
```

}

When i access this in browser the output is :-
[image]

i am previously worked with zend framework but new in symfony2. Any help will appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find the issue and it is really a silly mistake.

For get an repository we should have to use the Bundle name with class name like this

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BitcoinMyBundle:User');
```